# How to display hotel review data within hotel offer search results with Amadeus API in Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amadeus

I am developing a Rails app with the Amadeus hotel offers API.

I am using the Amadeus gem to get hotel offers like this in my controller:

```
def hotel_offer_results
  amadeus = Amadeus::Client.new
  response = amadeus.shopping.hotel_offers.get(
    cityCode: @hotel_search.city_code,
    checkInDate: @hotel_search.check_in_date,
    checkOutDate: @hotel_search.check_out_date,
    roomQuantity: @hotel_search.room_quantity,
    adults: @hotel_search.adults
  )
  @hotel_offers = response.data 
end
```

This gives me a list of hotel offers without a problem.

Now, I want to display data from the Hotel Ratings (hotel-sentiments) API.

How can I take my list of hotel offers and append the `overallRating` to the results in a view?

The result would be like this:
Holiday Inn, $120, Overall rating: 93

The name and price are from the hotel offer results, but the rating is from the hotel-sentiments api endpoint.

What is a good way to combine these two API requests to get the desired result in a view?

Comment: Are you going to average all the sentiments together? Depending on how many hotels you intend to show on the screen this could be highly data intensive back and forth calling for all the sentiments for each hotel and then preprocessing the data before display.

Comment: Each hotel offer has a hotel id, and the hotel id is used to get the rating.

Comment: Yes I understood that from the documents but each hotel will have numerous sentiments each with their own "overallRating" there does not appear to be a singular overallRating other than the 1-5 star rating that is already in the hotel response

Comment: Yes, the challenge is using the hotel_offers API response to fetch the overallRating for each hotel in the list of hotel offers.